# Cómo llamar una clase javascript externa en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy tratando de llamar una clase javascript dentro de mi archivo jsx para implementar unas animaciones a mi formulario pero no he podido hacerlo bien, ya intenté llamarlo con la etiqueta script dentro del jsx pero no funciona, también probé con el npm i react-script-tag pero cuando importo la librería me dice que no existe. Qué podría hacer?

Tratando de llamar el archivo js desde el jsx con

```
return (
<>
<main>
  <div className="contenedor-todo">
    <div class="caja-trasera">
      <div class="caja-trasera-login">
        <h3>¿Ya tienes una cuenta?</h3>
        <p>Inicia sesión para entrar en la página</p>
        <button id="btn-iniciar-sesion">Iniciar Sesión</button>
      </div>
      <div class="caja-trasera-register">
        <h3>¿Aún no tienes una cuenta?</h3>
        <p>Regístrate para que puedas iniciar sesión</p>
        <button id="btn-registrarse">Regístrarse</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor-login-register">
      <form action="" class="formulario-login">
        <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
        <button>Entrar</button>
      </form>

      <form action="" class="formulario-register">
        <h2>Regístrarse</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
        <button onClick={ handleSignup }>Registrarse</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</>
);
```

Tratando con react-script-tag

```
import { ScriptTag } from 'react-script-tag'
```

Pero cuando inicie el servidor me dice que el módulo no existe

Solamente quiero poder llamar la clase js a mi jsx para que mi form haga unas animaciones

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: A ver lo mejor seria quye mostraras tambien el error en formato codigo, pero asi a voz de pronto puede ser causa de diferentes cosas, como que el nombre del archivo no este bien, que la direccion del archivo(nombre incluido ) esten mal, es decir que no sea "./js/script.js", sino "../js/script.js" .
O que el nombre de las funciones esten mal